# Image does not fill width in ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

Setting a photo to an ImageView does not work as i expect. It does not fill the width completely.
[image] 
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unnamed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried with  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and still no change.

The first image is not shown completelly. The second one is in portraid mode and it's ok.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to your imageView

Comment: i did before, from xml/ java as well but nothing changed. i dont get why really.

Comment: try removing  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

Comment: nope :(. I have put a sysout, after setting the image to imageView ansd scalling to FITXY and: width: 512, height: 320. So, the image is not small..

Comment: the problem is not here, is using a viewpager. it does not look ok , because there is a method "public float getPageWidth(int position)" and this returns a float between 0.0f and 1.0f. I don't know how to use this so it does not matter if the image has a bigger width then another. but thx. your response was correct.